# Advice on choosing a pre-print server (Social Sciences)

Tags: publications, preprint, social-science

I have submitted an article to a journal for peer review. The journal allows the manuscript to be submitted to a non-commercial pre-print server at any time. I am new to publishing, and am wondering what I should take into consideration before choosing a pre-print server? For additional information I am working within the social sciences, are there any servers you would recommend for this? What is the general attitude towards places like SSRN who have been bought out by Elsevier?

Comment: Where do other people in your field post pre-prints/where do you go to read them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [SocArXiv](https://osf.io/preprints/socarxiv) given its (non-profit) organisation's yearlong commitment to openness. In addition, it offers high quality metadata via CrossRef (accessible through DOIs assigned by SocArXiv).

SSRN is rather questionable due to its link to Elsevier. Until recently, for instance, it required users to register an account and login in order to access preprints -- a rather frustrating user experience which diminishes the practical notion of "openness". In addition, [Elsevier is suspected of collecting personal data](https://eiko-fried.com/welcome-to-hotel-elsevier-you-can-check-out-any-time-you-like-not/) in an ample manner. Finally, SSRN preprints are not assigned DOIs.